# Semisimple subgroup of Euclidean group

Tags: gr.group-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $G$ be a closed and connected semisimple subgroup of the Euclidean group $E(n)$ (the group of isometries of $\mathbb R^n$).

Can we prove that $G$ is conjugate to a subgroup of $O(n)$?

Comment: I think you can do it by noting that we have the quotient homomorphism $q: E(n)\to\mathrm{O}(n)$, and homomorphic images of semisimple Lie algebras are semisimple.

Comment: More directly, use the fact that $G$ is semi-simple.  The restriction of the natural (linear)representation of $E(n)$ on $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ preserves the subrepresentation $\mathbb{R}^n$ and hence, by Weyl's theorem, it must be the direct sum of $\mathbb{R}^n$ with a $1$-dimensional complimentary subrepresentation $L\subset\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$.  This subrepresentation determines a fixed point of $G$ acting on $\mathbb{R}^n$.  Hence $G$ is conjugate to a subgroup of $\mathrm{O}(n)$.